# SonataAdmin $formMapper->add() entity filtering

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I have two entities: `Worker` and `User`. I created one to one relationship between them:

```
class Worker
{    
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="worker")
     */
    protected $user;

    ...
}

class User extends BaseUser
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Luny\SiteBundle\Entity\Worker", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $worker;

    ...
}
```

Now, using SonataAdminBundle I create page for editing worker. There I use FormMapper to create form. It looks something like this:

```
class WorkerAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('fname', 'text', array('label' => 'First Name'))
            ->add('lname', 'text', array('label' => 'Last Name'))
            ->add('user');
    }
}
```

This code generates for 'user' field next html-code:

```
<select id="s547d83b883c77_user" name="s547d83b883c77[user]" class="select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" title="User">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="2">test</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">test2</option>
</select>
```

Now, if I try to edit another worker, I want it not to show users which are already connected to other workers. How can I do it?

I'm very new in Symfony, so if all I wrote above is not exhaustive information, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class WorkerAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('fname', 'text', array('label' => 'First Name'))
            ->add('lname', 'text', array('label' => 'Last Name'))
            ->add('User', null, array(
                'class' => 'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User',
                'query_builder' => function($repository) {
                    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                            ->leftJoin('u.worker', 'w')
                            ->where('w is null');
                }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying this I got error:A single-valued association path expression to an inverse side is not supported in DQL queries. Use an explicit join instead.

Comment: Almost correct, but there are few problems. First, I have got to use `join('MyBundle\Entity\Worker', 'w')` or I got error (unknown class or something). Second, described relation adds field `user_id` to Worker table and adds nothing to User table. So I can't use `where('w is null')`. I can use `where('w.user is null')` but it is also incorrect 'cause it returns all users in case there is at least one worker without connection to user, otherwise it returns nothing. But I want it to select only users which are not listed in Worker table. Is it clear or I should explain again?

Comment: Regarding the first problem, I forgot to put the alias (edited). I'm not sure if I understood the second one though.

Comment: @devilcius I understand him. He mess up doctrine relationships and DB relationships. In the Doctrine all connections are stored in objects itself and when you do something like `SELECT u FROM AcmeUserBundle:User u JOIN u.worker w WHERE w IS NULL` in DQL you will have `SELECT [list of fields] FROM users u LEFT JOIN workers w ON u.id = w.user_id WHERE w.user_id IS NULL` in SQL. Doctrine knows where to put right SQL code.

Comment: Found the solution. Should to use leftJoin() instead of join(). Edited your answer. Thanks for your help.